# How to uppdate JTabbedPane GUI before actionPerformed ends?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtabbedpane, event-dispatch-thread

My java program use's a `JTabbedPane` and `JButton` objects to switch to next Tab in the tabbed pane. In one tab, in the button's `actionPerformed` method, I first make a call to switch tab then make a another method call that takes a couple of seconds to finish.

But the new tab doesn't show until the the action performed method is finished, meaning I have to wait for a couple of seconds before GUI updates. How do you update the GUI sooner, can this be done?

I rather don't use threads for this. Here's an example on how it looks:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
   //I want the new Tab to be visible before the lines below are executed, but it    
   //do not.     
   tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(2); 
   //This method takes a couple of seconds to finish
   methodDoSomething();
   //actionPeformed ends and now the JTabbedPane updates it's gui to show the next     
   //Tab after an annoying delay.
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do long-running tasks on the EDT. Look into Swing concurrency or a SwingWorker instead.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: *"I rather don't use threads for this."*  I want a flying pony that excretes ice-cream.  We don't always get what we want.